# jQuery plugin for "more content alert"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to find a jQuery plugin for the following situation:

I have a long DIV box that has a lot of important content in it. I've seen in different places where sites have a light overlay of a bar/arrows of some sort that float on the bottom of the screen if there is more content below, alerting the user that there's more.

Any ideas if there is a plugin for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a plugin. Set the div's css to overflow: hidden. Add a link/image/whatever that toggles display: block on the div when you click it.